# JAVA class implementation and extension issues

Tags: java, class, interface, eclipse-juno, zest

We have 2 JAVA classes related to a project, call them *AGraph* and *CallGraph*. We also have an interface named *Graphism* which is implemented by *AGraph*. There's one abstract class we have, named *GraphSnippet*, which basically creates a visualization of a ZEST graph.

Now, we want *CallGraph* to extend *AGraph*. My silly doubt here is, does *CallGraph* need to implement the interface *Graphism* as well?

Next, instead of making *GraphSnippet* an instance of the *Graph* class (*Graph* is a pre-defined class in the ZEST package), we want it to be an instance of *CallGraph* so that the functionalities of *CallGraph* and *AGraph* become a part of the implementation. And because we'll need the class *AGraph* during the later stages, we can't really knock this class out and get all its methods implemented in *CallGraph*.

Could someone help us with how to start with it? It's difficult for us, novice JAVA programmers, to figure out a way?

PS: We're working on Eclipse-JUNO.

Comment: wait, you said that AGraph implements Graphism in the 1st paragraph. What do you mean by your *silly doubt*?

Comment: You should try to clarify your question; talk about interfaces and classes only, not object.  In particular `GraphSnippet an object of the Graph` makes no sense.

Comment: Your first two questions doesn't strike well. First your `AGraph` already implements `Graphism`, so what's the point? Secondly, we don't see any `Graph` class, of which you want `GraphSnippet` to be an object of. Please take a look at your question once again.

Comment: @Sujay, sorry for the typo. I corrected the statement.

Comment: @Rohit Jain, when I said Graph class, I meant the predefined Graph class that's a part of the ZEST package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now, we want CallGraph to extend AGraph. My silly doubt here is, does
>   CallGraph need to implement the interface Graphism as well?

Yes, but you won't have to do anything.  Because it extends from AGraph, it will already implement Graphism.  You won't have to mark this anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was unnecessarily confused.